# Google Search Console reports back links from a number of non-existing domains pointing to my site

Tags: seo, google-search-console, backlinks, google-ranking, disavow-links

In Google Search Console, there are a high number of links from domains which actually do not exists,pointing to more than one posts on my site. My site is losing organic traffic day by day.  Should I disavow these links?

also got strange redirect links from this domain
`http-redirect.blogspot.com`

**Here are some of the domains** **out of 54**:

```
 - quicktopic.com
 - felsebiyatdergisi.com
 - eddiecheever.net
 - kazco.info
 - bhints.com
 - kwlai.com
 - stbarbmassillon.com
 - fopp.info
```

Comment: `blogspot.com` is Google domain...

Answer (score 1):

Unless you got a manual penalty from Google, these links are not the reason for your traffic drop - Google is very good at ignoring SPAM links like these, so in most cases, you can completely ignore it

You only need to disavow them if a big percentage of your links are from these SPAM websites, or if you start getting many of these every month.

Comment: I don't know who is behind those domains, but some of my sites have backlinks from those urls too. And many other page owners I know have them too. I completely agree with Andre: Google should be clever enough to ignore them. However if those links represent a big amount of Backlinks, just disavow them.